# Heroku schema not updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I reordered some columns with this migration

```
change_column :employee_connections_sections, :total_points, :integer, after: :profile_id
```

However, after pushing to Heroku and viewing the Heroku pg console, my schema isn't being updated to be in sync with my Rails app.

I've tried dropping my Heroku db and the heroku restart command. I am using a free instance of Heroku, so I do not know if that would cause any issues.

If anyone has any insight, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: what command did you use to run migrations on heroku?

Comment: heroku run rake db:migrate, then after that migration, heroku restart, so that the schema would be updated.

Comment: did you $git add , $git commit, and $git push first?

Comment: Of course. I'm wondering if the Heroku postgresql can interpret the reordering of the columns (ex: I want total points to come after profile_id). Works fine in development using MySQL. However, after deployment, doesn't update Heroku schema.